# Linux force process release memory while memory usage high?

Tags: memory-management

I implement an service by C on my linux(CENT-OS-5). I found that service

consume more and more memory day by day. (about 200-500KB per day)

I knew that memory once allocated via malloc is not easy to return to

system. So maybe it is why my program keep growing memory size.

After I tried to write a simple code to malloc all memory from system.

Something happened to my linux. RSS-Memory of my service went down from 6xxxKB to 3xxx KB.

So my question is: Did Linux recycle memory in emergency situation? If yes,

how it works? Can I configure it? Thank you.

Comment: Memory allocated by `malloc` is *very* easy to "return to system", just pass a pointer to the memory to the `free` function. You *do* free memory once you're done with it?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please read this doc about what to ask in StackOverflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow). Your question is a valid one, but in this [other forum, SuperUser](https://superuser.com/tour). Welcome to this communtity, hope to see more posts of you.

Comment: Yes, I free almost what I have allocated, but calling 'free' can not reduce  RSS  value shown by 'ps aux'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there's a memory recycle mechanism called PFRA, maybe it a the answer to my question